# GNU make won't recognize POSIX format path

Tags: cygwin, gnu-make

Here is the GNU Make version that I installed on my windows 10 pc today with the cygwin setup tool:

```
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-unknown-cygwin
```

I have a simple test makefile:

```
include /c/temp/vs.mk
```

When I do make, I got the following error:

```
makefile:1: /c/temp/vs.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '/c/temp/vs.mk'.  Stop.
```

When I change the line to

```
include c:\temp\vs.mk
```

it works.

I thought any built-for-cygwin GNU make should recognize POSIX path format instead of Windows path format, but this simple test showed me otherwise for my version of GNU Make.

Now, I have another windows 7 pc that I installed with the following GNU Make version long time ago:

```
GNU Make 3.81
This program built for i686-pc-cygwin
```

When I tested make, both POSIX path format and Windows path format worked.

I did quite a lot search on google, but no relevant information would explain me why this happened.

Comment: Have you tried : /cygdrive/c/temp/vs.mk ?

Comment: That works! Is this an added feature for cygwin later than 3.81?

Comment: Seems it's there since long time now. Not sure if it's since 3.81

Answer (score 1):

This is not a POSIX path for Cygwin

```
/c/temp/vs.mk
```

to verify we can show the root content

```
 $ ls -1F /
bin/
cygdrive/
Cygwin.bat*
Cygwin.ico
Cygwin64_Terminal.lnk*
Cygwin-Terminal.ico
dev/
etc/
home/
lib/
proc/
sbin/
srv/
tmp/
usr/
var/
```

There is no "C" directory
Where are the Windows Drive Letters ? They are mounted under `/cygdrive`

```
$ ls -1F /cygdrive
c/
d/
e/
```

That setting/behaviour is the default from when Cygwin was created.
When you need to make conversions between Windows and Posix path or viceversa, use `cygpath`

```
$ cygpath -u "c:\temp\vs.mk"
/cygdrive/c/temp/vs.mk 

$ cygpath -w /cygdrive/c/temp/vs.mk
C:\temp\vs.mk
```

Comment: OK, this helps, but do you know why ```/c/temp/vs.mk``` worked for the GNU make 3.81 I installed on the other machine?

Comment: May be it was NOT the Cygwin make.  Surely there is no special code in the Cygwin make from 4.1-1 released in 2015 https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2015-02/msg00097.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I recall, Cygwin provides its own version of GNU make that supports Cygwin paths.  I think (can't remember) that there are code changes needed to allow GNU make to work with Cygwin paths.

You probably should describe how you built this version of GNU make, and you should remove the `makefile` tag from this question and add the `gnu-make` and `cygwin` tags... some folks familiar with Cygwin may show up to help.

Comment: I didn't build this version. I installed it with the cygwin setup tool. Thanks for the advice and I have added the tags.

Comment: Oh, then definitely you need to check with the cygwin folks about this.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have found out why this happened.

Basically, there is a file `cygwinfolder/etc/fstab` that can be modified to specify the cygdrive path prefix. The default cygdrive path prefix is `/cygdrive`, and that's why the POSIX path prefixed with `/cygdrive` works for a clean install as in my first machine. Here is what's in the `fstab` file in my first machine:

```
none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,posix=0,user 0 0
```

In my second machine, I have modified this file long time ago and I forgot about it. It has set the cygdrive path prefix to `/`. Here is what's in the `fstab` file:

```
none / cygdrive binary,posix=0,user 0 0
```

For more details, refer to https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#cygdrive.